# js datetime regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date, datetime, time

I am looking for a js regex for datetime.
The regex should allow:
Only valid (optional, date validity will be checked later as well) date formmated dd/mm/yyyy, or the expressions: today, tomarrow, now, in x days/hours/years/minutes, if date is provided in one of the ways that dosent include "in x hours/minuts" or "now", the the time will be specified as well in the format hh:mm or hh:mm PM/AM or hh or hh PM/AM. If there is a regex that fit some of the rules but not all it will be ok as well.
For example:

```
 now
 in 5 days 12 AM
 25/6/2020 14:05
 tomorrow 13
```

Comment: @Utkanos I didn't intend to have any code written for me. In most cases for popular regexs such as date or email there is an already made for it somewhere. I did try my own regex but it works on conventional dates only dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format. Didn't know how the expand it to the special cases as well.

Comment: In that case you're asking for an off–site resource, which is off topic here.

Comment: @RobG what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression ? It asks for off site resources, it dosent provide any code, yet. It has over 3000 upvotes

Comment: @avivgood2—thanks, I've voted to close it. It's been edited beyond recognition from the original question, which included code. But that was edited out many years ago. What you've posted is a request for someone else to write code for you, or point you to some other resource without any attempt at writing code yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you mean something like?

```
let r = /(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})|today|tomorrow|now|(in\s+\d+\s+(days|hours|years|minutes)(\s+\d{1,2}(:\d{2})?\s*(AM|PM))?)|\d{2}(:\d{1,2})?\s*(PM|AM)?/
r.test("please bring it to me tomorrow in 5PM okay?") // true
```

Comment: Greate soulotion! And if I don't allow words which not part of the date such as "please bring it to me " or "in" (in case of  your example)

Comment: Readability of this solution is 0%. It would be better to split it to separate ifs.

Comment: This does not validate the date, it just checks that it's a valid format. E.g. `r.test('99/99/9999')` returns true.

Comment: @RobG But i said date validation is optional